# How about reviews/ratings of developer components/libraries?

Tags: feature-request

Whenever I buy a book, I go to amazon and look up the ratings there. I have noticed that it's really hard to find any kind of review or rating for developer components and libraries. 
There are so many knowledgeable users so I think it would be great to add this feature to stackoverflow.
What do you think?

Answer (score 2):

It might be interesting as a sister project, but library reviews is a fair deviation from a Q&A site, so I can't quite picture it being part of SO proper.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's acceptable to ask questions asking for good and bad features of components or libraries (though others will disagree).  Of course, a lot have already been asked.

Comment: Indeed, there are a lot of "what's the best library to do X", and some of them are closed as subjective, if the question is not specific enough.